# Can't access returned json in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

This is probably something simple that I'm missing, but I've been googling around looking for an answer, and haven't gotten anything to work.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm making an ajax call to my server to get some simple data returned as json

**The issues I'm having:**

I've tried a few methods to access the json data, but have gotten errors ranging from "undefined", "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property...", to "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o".

**What I've tried:**

Here's the jquery (v1.11.1) ajax call:

```
$.getJSON(ajax_url, function(data){

    // I've tried the commented out items below
    // var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    // var data = JSON.parse(data);
    // var data = data[0];

    alert(data.test);

});
```

To make things super simple, I've tried and failed to get access to the very simple json returned by the following php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$test = array('test' => 'test data');
echo json_encode($test);
exit;
```

Before anyone asks, I've double checked to make sure that the ajax_url is accessing the proper page by logging the url to the js console and also logging the access on the php side by making an error log entry when the script is called.

**What I'd like:**

I'd love it if someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong, and how I can easily get the "test data" from the "test" key being returned.

Edit:

Running console.log(data) gives the following info:

```
Object {success: "true"}
```

Edit Edit:

The issue was echoing the success => true array higher in my actual script. I forgot to delete it before adding the test => test data.

Comment: start by console.log(data)

Comment: what about alerting `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: check if the request is being sent in the "network" tab of your development console, if it is then check the response you getting

Comment: @mplungjan I added the output to the bottom of my post.

Comment: `data` is an object with a single property, `success`. You can access the success value via `data.success`. It's not a string containing JSON, so you cannot parse it. In fact, `$.getJSON` *already* parsed the JSON for you, that's it's whole purpose. It also isn't an array, so you cannot access the first element of it (`data[0]`). It seems like you are not returning the data from your PHP script that you claim you do.

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil that gives me the json as a string: {"success":"true"}

Comment: what do you get if you go directly to the Ajax URL in your browser? And are you sure it is using the correct ajax_url?

Comment: can please provide the console output from `ajax_url` or check if it's point to the correct url. it seems to that the wrong url is loaded.

Comment: Typically, the unexpected token error indicates that it's not valid JSON, for whatever reason. There's an excellent chance that the entire thing is simply enclosed in quotes. This kind of thing can be pretty maddening, that's for sure.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not sure what you mean, I'm getting a string of json back and have verified that by logging data to the console (see my edit), and using the stringify alert that Med.Amine.Touli suggested.

Comment: @skroczek please read the full post before commenting.

Comment: @rmmoul: The very fact that `console.log(data)` outputs `Object {success: "true"}` proofs that `data` is a JavaScript object. If you don't believe me, do `console.log(typeof data)`. `$.getJSON` **already parsed** the JSON for you. That's what `$.getJSON` does.

Comment: @rmmoul take look at my answer. if it returns a json as string so it ll work

Comment: @CargoMeister: The OP is getting the error because they are trying to parse a JavaScript object as JSON. Easiest way to replicate the error: `JSON.parse({})`.

Comment: @rmmoul my fault, but then you should update your code by using `$test = new \stdClass(); $a->success = true;` to be consistent in your example if "Object {success: "true"}" is the potential right response of your script.

Comment: @FelixKling As an aside, I was returning json. My actual json response was the success => true, which is what I needed to return for my project. I forgot to delete it before adding the test data used in my question. The answer was to access the value of success using data.success. Thanks for taking the time to bring me around to looking at the file a little closer.

Comment: Oh, I know that the PHP script returns JSON. My point was that `data` is already the parsed response. `$.getJSON`'s whole purpose is to parse the JSON for you, so that you don't have to do it anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You can't access `data.test` because you are not receiving an object with property `test`. Either you are hitting the wrong URL, or you are generating different data than you claim.

---

The very fact that `console.log(data)` outputs `Object {success: "true"}` tells you that `data` is a JavaScript object. Proof:

```
> console.log({success: true});
Object {success: true}
```

If it was a string containing JSON, you would see this instead:

```
> console.log('{"success": true}');
 {"success": true}
```

So, `data` is an object with a single property, `success`. You can access the success value via `data.success`. It's not a string containing JSON, so you cannot parse it. In fact, `$.getJSON` **already parsed** the JSON for you, that's its whole purpose:

> The `success` callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the `$.parseJSON()` method.

It also isn't an array, so you cannot access the first element of it (`data[0]`).

> I've tried a few methods to access the json data, but have gotten errors ranging from "undefined", "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property...", to "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o".

You got the syntax error because you tried to parse a JavaScript as JSON. Simplest way to replicate the error:

```
> JSON.parse({});
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

That's because `JSON.parse` expects a **string**. If the argument is not a string, it is converted to one. And what is an object converted to?

```
> String({})
"[object Object]"
```

So you and up calling `JSON.parse("[object Object]")` and `"[object Object]"` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Looks like this was an error on my part. Higher up in my actual script I was creating the $test = array('success' => 'true'); and echoing it then exiting. So it's working properly, and I just missed this mistake in my haste.

Comment: You did a very good job with the question, it contained all the relevant information. I'm upset with the others who apparently didn't look at that information properly (and thus lead you into a very wrong direction).

Comment: Really I should have looked close. The success => true wasn't registering as a mistake because that was the actual response I was trying to get, and in my frustration (not knowing I could access data.success directly) I totally missed my mistake.

Comment: More information about objects, in case you need it (don't know your background): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Thanks. 5 years of doing this full time, but this was the first time I needed to parse json with javascript and didn't realize jquery's getJSON() set it up for me. It's always the stupid simple problems that bite the hardest.

Comment: @rmmoul: You can use `$.get` if you want to do it yourself ;) Anyways, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

so your if it returns a json as string so your data is ok 
try this code

```
var tempData = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(tempData, function(k, v) {
    //display the key and value pair
    alert("key= " + k + "and value= "+ v);
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. It returns a promise.

Comment: @FelixKling i didnt use getJSON ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. However, `data` is already an object, so it can't be parsed.